# How to plot title of the column in a histogram?

Tags: r, plot

I have a data frame like this

```
   >df
               X1       X2       X3       X4       X5       X6
2016-02-16 120.1142 124.8521 119.0029 119.2219 129.4915 116.5805
2016-02-17 122.1224 121.7848 123.8320 125.2890 125.6411 119.2096
2016-02-18 123.7764 126.1593 126.2566 120.5896 124.5153 123.2499
2016-02-19 119.5436 124.8069 118.0718 121.8618 123.3318 123.5650
2016-02-20 123.5873 126.0524 121.6285 118.9005 122.1214 123.5694
```

I want to plot histogram with column name as the title.

I am using this code

```
par(mfrow = c(2,3))
for(i in names(df)){
hist(df[[i]], main=colnames(df[[i]]),xlab="x")
}
```

buts its showing nothing.

```
> colnames(df[[i]])
NULL
```

How can i plot histogram with column name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've done here doesn't work:

```
par(mfrow = c(2,3))
for(i in names(df)){
hist(df[[i]], main=colnames(df[[i]]),xlab="x")
}
```

because `df[[i]]` is just the vector from the data frame, and vectors don't have colnames. You've already got the name you want in `i`, so why not:

```
hist(df[[i]], main=i, xlab="x")
```

It might be better practice not to call your loop variable `i`, because that smells like a number to most people. Use `n` or `name` for clarity.

Answer (score 5):

Try `mapply`

```
mapply(hist,as.data.frame(df),main=colnames(df),xlab="x")
```

[image]